# Search files in subfolders, and assign them in workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

currently I am trying to get specific files inside subfolders.

Example:
I have a folder named: **A**
Inside the folder named A, I have subfolders called **X Y Z**.
inside this subfolders I have .mat files that I need to "print" by *assignin* command into Matlabs workspace.

How can I do it ?

I tried by *dir* command (but dir only give me the name of the folders X Y Z, so I tried to get the code to get the folders X Y Z and then to get this '*.mat' files but I can not.

Any idea ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code and the results you get

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you started in the right direction with `dir`. Perhaps you did not realize that you can assign its output to a file.

Here is a small example, but I think this should be sufficient for you to succeed.

This assumes that you have your current directory, and that it only contains X, Y, and Z.
Now you can get all files in those folders like so:

```
d=dir;
for t=3:numel(d)
    d(t).subdirectories = dir(d(t).name);
end
```

Now you can just loop through them and process all interesting files.

Comment: @user3202744 I assume you solved the problem then? You can now access a file by `load(fullfile(d(t).name,d(t).subdirectories(3).name))` for example.

Comment: Hi Dennis, 
Thanks again for the answer. I still do not resolved the problem.
Now what I have is the name of the subfolders but not the files in in. The "for" code that you have written allows me to get this subfolders names from the principal folder. But now I can not acces to the files in subfolders. the "load(fullfile(d(t).name,d(t).subdirectories(3).name))" give me error of matrix dimensions.